# Why is "natural_feature" excluded from Google Maps Geocoding and Places API searches?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api, google-places

Trying to mimic the 'what's here' feature of Google Maps in my own website but it seems that items of type 'natural_feature' are excluded from Google Maps 3 API geocoding and places searches, both nearby and radar, and also on text searches unless the EXACT name of the place is provided. This must have been an informed choice by Google to do this - anyone know the rationale, and better, offer a workaround? Seems crazy that I can't get the names of woods, nature reserves etc. any more...

Comment: They are excluded from the geocoding API because they are not postal addresses.  Can't speak to the places API.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do it! If you get a geocoding API key from Google you can get all the data for natural features included in the JSON/XML response from a server request like the following (I was trying to get the data for "Gamsey Wood"):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.4180698,-0.2029999&result_type=natural_feature&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_GEO_KEY

Happy days!

Comment: I'm afraid your solution relied on a non-documented behavior that just went away, it only gets ZERO_RESULTS now. You'd probably be interested in https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4759&q=apitype%3AGeocoder%20type%3AEnhancement%20reverse&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Comment: This is extremely annoying as I helped with putting boundaries and names to several local features. It would be interesting to know why Google have made this info progressively harder to access, and now apparently impossible.

Comment: I have made my feelings known on the gmaps_api_issues forum :-(