# Google Geocoding Api returning inconsistent data

Tags: missing-data, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to understand how to get correct data from the Google Geocoding api, and i cannot understand how to get the correct data.

I am trying to get the the city Costa Calma on the island Fuerteventura
When i look up the city with the url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Costa%20Calma,%20Fuerteventura

I get the response:

```
{  
"results":[  
    {  
        "address_components":[  
            {  
                "long_name":"Costa Calma",
                "short_name":"Costa Calma",
                "types":[  
                    "locality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {  
                "long_name":"Pájara",
                "short_name":"Pájara",
                "types":[  
                    "administrative_area_level_4",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {  
                "long_name":"Jandía",
                "short_name":"Jandía",
                "types":[  
                    "administrative_area_level_3",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {  
                "long_name":"Las Palmas",
                "short_name":"Las Palmas",
                "types":[  
                    "administrative_area_level_2",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {  
                "long_name":"Canarias",
                "short_name":"CN",
                "types":[  
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {  
                "long_name":"Spain",
                "short_name":"ES",
                "types":[  
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address":"Costa Calma, Las Palmas, Spain",
        "geometry":{  
            "bounds":{  
                "northeast":{  
                    "lat":28.1747078,
                    "lng":-14.2126396
                },
                "southwest":{  
                    "lat":28.147027,
                    "lng":-14.2368948
                }
            },
            "location":{  
                "lat":28.1585283,
                "lng":-14.2294205
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{  
                "northeast":{  
                    "lat":28.1747078,
                    "lng":-14.2126396
                },
                "southwest":{  
                    "lat":28.147027,
                    "lng":-14.2368948
                }
            }
        },
        "partial_match":true,
        "place_id":"ChIJ2fWZIEOcRwwRjXhqKnxec8U",
        "types":[  
            "locality",
            "political"
        ]
    }
],
"status":"OK"}
```

I can see in that response that Costa Calma is located on the Canarias, but i cannot see on what island, while if i lookup Fuerteventura, with the url:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Fuerteventura,%20Spanien
I get the response

```
{
"results": [{
    "address_components": [{
        "long_name": "Fuerteventura",
        "short_name": "Fuerteventura",
        "types": ["natural_feature", "establishment"]
    }, {
        "long_name": "Spain",
        "short_name": "ES",
        "types": ["country", "political"]
    }],
    "formatted_address": "Fuerteventura, Spain",
    "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
            "northeast": {
                "lat": 28.757003,
                "lng": -13.8224231
            },
            "southwest": {
                "lat": 28.0438891,
                "lng": -14.5101955
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "lat": 28.3982211,
            "lng": -14.0103493
        },
        "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
                "lat": 28.757003,
                "lng": -13.8224231
            },
            "southwest": {
                "lat": 28.0438891,
                "lng": -14.5101955
            }
        }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJgQ_Cr3OkRwwRI3-1tRMcxyo",
    "types": ["natural_feature", "establishment"]
}],
"status": "OK"}
```

I can see that Fuerteventura is located in Spain, not but not in the Canarias, however if i check the coordinates, i can see the coordinates are on the same island, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`Fuerteventura` seems to be an island located as one of `Spain`'s canary islands

Comment: It is, and Costa Calma is located on Fuerteventura, but when i lookup Costa Calma it says that it's just located on the canary islands, but how can i make so when i lookup Costa Calma i get Fuerteventura as the island?

Comment: I have tried a few combinations and it seems `Google` doesn't provide the island name, just provides the group naming of islands `Canarias`

Answer (score 0):

Fuerteventura is an island, and while it could have been also a political division, it is not. That's why you will not see Fuerteventura (or any island name) in a postal address in Canary Islands. And that's why it will never be in the `address_components` of any geocode result.

I'm not sure what's the problem at hand, but I can tell you from first-hand experience that you should not need "Fuerteventura" as part of an address. Addresses in Canary Islands use only the locality, postal code and province, and there are only 2 provinces, each containing roughly half of Canary Islands.

I reckon it can be confusing that both provinces are named after the capital city of each of them:

- The province of [Santa Cruz de Tenerife](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26in_administrative_area%3DSanta%2520Cruz%2520de%2520Tenerife), containing the island of [Tenerife](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DTenerife) and everything East of it, is named exactly as the capital city in the island of Tenerife ([Santa Cruz de Tenerife](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DSanta%2520Cruz%2520de%2520Tenerife)).
- The province of [Las Palmas](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26in_administrative_area%3DLas%2520Palmas), containing the island of Gran Canaria and everything West of it, is named after the capital city in the island of [Gran Canaria](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DGran%2520Canaria) ([Las Palmas de Gran Canaria](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DLas%2520Palmas%2520de%2520Gran%2520Canaria)).

If you would like to get islands in general, see [Why is "natural_feature" excluded from Google Maps Geocoding and Places API searches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545879/why-is-natural-feature-excluded-from-google-maps-geocoding-and-places-api-sear) and https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4759

Comment: The reason why I would need Fuerteventura, is that I am working in a travel destination API,
Where the important parts in this case is that:
Fuerteventura is a part of the Canary Islands, which is a part of Spain.
The city it self is not the most important part.

Comment: Looks like you really are looking for https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4759 then.